# Using Product and Location Models, how to find "deals" near locations (Rails 3.1.1)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I have a Product Model having deals of stores (another Model Store) in whole city. Now if someone selects particular store I want my view to display deals of all stores in geographically nearby areas of that store (say within range of 3 miles).

One way would be finding all deals on zipcode basis. But wondering if there is any better way to do this. Maybe some gem..

Thanks.

Comment: what about [geo-kit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/index.html) plugin for Rails..you will have to store the geocodes for all stores in database (by geocoding address on creating a store)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use geokit gem: http://geokit.rubyforge.org/ .  Example:

```
Store.find(:all, :origin =>[37.792,-122.393], :within=>10)
```

If works with relational database. However, it is not optimized like Geo spatial databases.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a spatial database. You can achieve this with Postgres via [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/). I'd also highly recommend using [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) or [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) as a front-end to PostGIS. You're going to want to do some serious reading on GIS in general. This is not a topic to cover in a single answer. You may want to spend some time poking around the [OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/) site.

If you're feeling trendy, you can use [MongoDB's spatial indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing). This is probably what I would recommend if you're looking for a quick fix. FourSquare actually runs entirely on MongoDB's spatial functionality. It's what they use to find people close-by. So with Mongo you could find nearby deals with something like

```js
db.deals.find({
  loc: {
    $near: [YOUR_X, YOUR_Y],
    $maxDistance : DEAL_DISTANCE
  }
});
```

This will return all deals that are within `DEAL_DISTANCE` of your coordinates.